# Interpreting complicated nested loops

Tags: r, for-loop, nested

How would you interpet the "else" part of this nested for loop?

I have given my attempt at the bottom but I am struggling to get my head around how the else part functions considering that a is already defined.  The result of y(1,2,3,4) is 16, so by my calculations that vector increases by a value of 6 at that step, since the other steps don't hold.

```
y=function(a,b,c,d)
{
if(a>b){
 while(b<d){
  b=b+a
}
for(e in c(a,c,d)){
b=b-e
}}
else{
for(a in 1:c){
  a=a+d
}}
if(b>c){
c= c*d + a-b}
 return(sum(a,b,c,d))
}

y(1,2,3,4)
```

My interpretation:

Only valid if a > b (if not: skip to "else step")
Keep adding a to b, as long as it doesnt exceed b (stop the last step before it does)
Say e in c(a=1, b=2, c=3), we would do (b - a - c - d) or technically b-1, then (b-1)-2, then (b-3)-3 b=b-e

Only if a < b it applies - This is the part I don't understand????

Next step after the first if/else loop: just recalculate c with latest values of a,b,d,c from after the first loop
Sum all the elements of the final vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what appears to be happening when you call y(1,2,3,4)

```
# First check if a > b
# a = 1, b = 2 do nothing
#
# else if a < b then run for loop
# for(a in 1:c) 
#   first run through
#     a = 1
#     a = 1 + 4
#     a = 5
#   second run through
#     a = 2 (Note a has been overwritten as to by for loop iteration)
#     a = 2 + 4
#     a = 6
#   third and final run through
#     a = 3 (Note a has again been overwritten by for loop iteration)
#     a = 3 + 4
#     a = 7
#
# After for loop completes check if b > c
# b = 2, c = 3 do nothing
#
# return statement
# sum all values
# a = 7, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4
# 7 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 16
# return 16
```